# Can I print the invoice without sending the customer an email?

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I want to print some invoices but my customer shouldn't receive an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In backend there is an option for  `system > configuration > sales > email > Invoice` => enabled = NO. [ keep this option NO ]

now take invoice for test order and check whether invoice will go to customer or not.